# How to get metadata in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, metadata

I am trying to work in QGIS and I am very inexperienced with it. I recently was able to import several shapefiles into a SpatiaLite database and I need metadata to go with these shapefiles. 4 out of 5 my shapefiles were created in QGIS and I put metadata in under their Properties, but I do not see this metadata when I open them from SpatiaLite. The other shapefile was download from a county GIS data portal but had no metadata entered in.

I have already tried the Metatools plugin, but the buttons where I can try and edit the metadata appear to be grayed out and I'm not sure how to fix it and use it.

How can I put in metadata for the shapefiles in the SpatiaLite database in QGIS?

Comment: Metadata are stored in QGIS projects. After editing the metadata of the layers on the layer properties window save your project and distribute the project with the data source (shp, spatialite, etc.).